# Discussion about std::vector<T> and standard array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, reference

Discussion about std::vector and standard array

Say if we have following code:

```
void myclass::loadArray(void *outData)
void myclass::loadVector(void *outData)


void myclass::func ()
{
//here we have a vector
std::vector<int> myVector;
myVector.resize(10)

// here we have an array
int myArray[10];
```

here I wonder what will be the differences between following implementations 
    //1: array
    myclass::loadArray(myArray)

```
//2: array 
myclass::loadArray(&(myArray[0]))


//1: vector
myclass::loadVector(myVector)

//2: vector
myclass::loadVector(&(myVector[0]))


}
```

From my understanding, Just depending on if we want to use array and vector we pick different solution.
There is no difference between 1 and 2. Could you please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What happened when you compiled and ran it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two versions with the array are equivalent: in the first, the array is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element, which the second creates explicitly.

The first version with the vector won't compile, since there is no implicit conversion to a pointer. You'll have to explictly get the address of the array; either as you do in the second version, or with `vector.data()`.

Answer (score 0):

1 and 2 will be the same for the array versions. In the first, the array will decay to a pointer to the first element, the second calls explicitly with a pointer to the first element.

The first vector version will not compile as you can't implicitly change a `std::vector` to a `void*`.

For the second vector version, you will be calling the function with a pointer to the first element stored in the vector, not the vector itself.